# how to assign borders for the elements inside the TD in html

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i have  table  unser it  i have  one  td

with  elemets  inside  the menu  are  coming dynamically from database that is .cs(c#) file i am  assging the  values
 ex: i have   admin, user,  manager like  these
  now  i need  to  assign vertical  boder  b/w   them  inside  the  td  like this

|admin| user |manager|
 as the  elements are  cmg  dynamicallly  how  to  assign   border  in between them
 any solution on this  would  be  great
  thank  you

Comment: While it can be hard for you to write English correctly, please take care of punctuation like dots and capitalization. It is one thing to do to make your text more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery (for example if you have table with id 'your_table_cell_id_here'), type in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#your_table_cell_id_here').css({'border-left' : '1px solid #000000', 'border-right' : '1px solid #000000'});
  });
</script>
```

or just make a new css style in your .css file:

```
.table_class td{
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

and don't forget to five your table a class 'table_class'.

Comment: thanks  for  ur  replay  ARTstudio
 $('#your_table_cell_id_here').css({'border-left' : '1px solid #000000', 'border-right' : '1px solid #000000'}); 
 here  my  td  id ="hrmenu"
 so  should  i replace  that   with  #your_table_cell_id_here'--> hrmenu